# QT images not rendered on IOS device

Tags: ios, qt, opengl-es

I am just loading images and render them to the screen:

```
int oldFBO  = 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &oldFBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, oldFBO);
    glViewport(0, 0, _width, _height);

    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);


    _program.bind();

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat)*3, (GLvoid*)0);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(_program.programId(), "u_texture"), 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

loading images:

```
QOpenGLTexture* depthImg;

if(!img.load(path.c_str()))
{
    qWarning("ERROR LOADING IMAGE");
    cout << "could not find the file: " << path << endl;
    return;
}else{
    cout << "loaded image: " << path << endl;
}

 depthImg = new QOpenGLTexture(img.mirrored());
 depthImg->setMinificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Nearest);
 depthImg->setMagnificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Linear);
```

This application runs on QT 5.8.0 and works on the CPU version. If I test the IOS simulator everything is fine to accept for rendering only in the left bottom corner of the OpenGlWidget.

But if I run the application on my iPhone device (Iphone 5s) it will not show me any images. The console said the images are loaded but nothing is shown on the screen. Also no GLerror is detected or building error of the shaders.

Also a difference is, that the simulator builds a version of:

OpenGL Context version: 3,0

GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00

and on my iPhone it's said:

OpenGL Context version: 2,0

GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00

The shaders should actually work for all:

```
    /* final.fsh */

uniform highp sampler2D u_texture;
varying highp vec4 qt_TexCoord0;

void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(u_texture, qt_TexCoord0.xy).xyz,1.0);
}

    /* final.vsh */

attribute highp vec3 a_position;

varying highp vec4 qt_TexCoord0;

void main(void)
{


    const mat4 B = mat4(0.5,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                            0.0,  0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
                            0.0,  0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
                            0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0);

    qt_TexCoord0 = B * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
    gl_Position =  vec4(a_position, 1.0);
}
```

I also try to force the glFormat in the main function with:

```
QSurfaceFormat glFormat;
glFormat.setVersion(2, 1);
glFormat.setDepthBufferSize(24);
glFormat.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(glFormat);
```

I have no idea why it has no problems to build in the simulator but does not show anything on the device

Comment: Have you tried changing the highp to mediump in the shaders? I believe not all devices on GLES 2 support highp.

Comment: No I did not test it. Because I had once images shown on my iPhone device. with the same application. I just changed the images. The images have the same formate and also the same name. I also delete the Xcode build and had QT rebuild it. I also tried with deinstalling the application from the iPhone and reinstall it.